# Converting EXCEL to JSON (row wise) in PYTHON

Tags: python, json, excel

I have the following excel file:

```
    ID   Designation   X     Y     Z
    001  President     1     4     8
         Chairman      7     2     0
    002  Director      3     1     9
     .      .          .     .     .
     .      .          .     .     .
```

I need the following output in json file for every UNIQUE ID as :

```
    {'001': []
     'Position': [{'Designation': 'President', 'X': [], 'Y': [], 'Z': []},
              {'Designation': 'Chairman','X': [], 'Y': [], 'Z': []} ]}
    {'002': []
     'Position': [{'Designation': 'Director', 'X': [], 'Y': [], 'Z': []} ]}
```

Comment: How can you store two `Position` key in one json in expected output ? Can you clear this thing what's your expected output ?

Comment: I am trying to store two 'values' for the 'key Position'. Its just like a list having many elements in the form of positions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid json. You need key-value pairs.
if `001` is the key, the `'Position'` should be a value and not a key to `[[{'Des..`

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Assuming for every ID key, the value is an [] . Can the output then be obtained?